# Can't run ionic cap add ios on Mac M1?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, apple-m1

I can't figure out what the issue is, I've updated Ionic to version 6.20, yet still there seems to be an issue when trying to add the iOS version of my project.

[log file of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sacGu.png)

[Ionic and Cocoapods versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVC4T.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run command in your ios platform folder inside `App` where your `PODFILE` exists: 
1). `arch -x86_64 pod update`  2). `arch -x86_64 pod install` . then run your project normally.

Comment: I did try what you wrote but no success.

Answer (score 0):

**After searching tons of answers, finally found the solution:**

- Uninstall Ruby
- Uninstall Cocoapods
- Unistall Capacitor

Then, in M1 Native, `DON'T` do `Rossetta compatibility mode` install those previous things you just uninstalled.

Then `npx cap add ios`, and everything should be running smoothly.